# Python: join two bytearray objects

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, concatenation

I would like to concatenate a bytearray to another bytearray. I thought this might work:

```
byt1 = bytearray(10)
byt2 = bytearray(10)
byt1.join(byt2)
print(repr(byt1))
```

> byt1.join(byt2)
>
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, int found

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: byt1.extend(byt2)

Comment: @TomLynch put it in an answer, thx!

Comment: ps i think i knew that already !! i feel like down-voting my question now (facepalm)

Comment: Even if that worked, it wouldn't do what you want: the `.join` method creates a new object, it doesn't perform an in-place mutation.  Also, `.join` doesn't concatenate. Consider `'abc'.join('123')`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Create a new combined bytearray from two:

```
byt_combined = byt1 + byt2
```

Extend one bytearray with another. This changes `byt1`:

```
byt1.extend(byt2)
```

Comment: Also, `byt1 += byt2` will do an in-place `.extend`, but using the method has the advantage that it will also mutate `byt1 ` even if it's not local.

Answer (score 11):

You can join a byte to an array like below:

```
    b"".join([bytearray(10), bytearray(10)])
```